# [Help]_How to set priority with specific interrupt without using CMSIS library cotex M0+?

Tags: arm, interrupt, 32-bit, nxp-microcontroller

Could anyone help me with an example about how to set priority in NVIC Cotex M0+ (only using register) ?

Many thanks.

Comment: read the arm documentation and set the bits in the register.  what part of this are you struggling with?

Comment: I have already set bits in the registers . Other registers : ISER, ICER, ... work well but the register of interrupt priority (IPR) does not have any value.
I do not know why.

Comment: so this is has nothing to do with CMSIS vs not CMSIS, but how do these registers or how does priority work?

Comment: what part of the documentation do you not understand?

Comment: please provide a minimal example or at least describe the values programmed into each related register and what your expectations are (and what happens instead)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, @old_timer. I am struggling how to post my function in this comment.

Comment: Here is my function:  `#define INT_U4_NVIC_BASEADDR                       0xE000E100

#define INT_NVIC_IPRO_OFFSET(id)             (0x300 + (U1)((id >> 2) << 2))
#define INT_NVIC_IPRO_MASK(id)               (uint32_t)(0xFF << ((id % 4)*8))

#define INT_NVICBASEADDR_IPRO_OFFSET(IRQn)   (INT_U4_NVIC_BASEADDR + INT_NVIC_IPRO_OFFSET(IRQn))

#define NVIC_4_PRIO    4U
void Int_Drv_NVICSetPriority(uint8_t u1IRQn, uint8_t u1Priority)
{
  (*(volatile uint32_t*)INT_NVICBASEADDR_IPRO_OFFSET(u1IRQn)) =  ((u1Priority << (8 - _NVIC_PRIO_BITS)) & 0xff);`